# Data binding Pivot control while data binding within each Pivot items data template

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

So I have an ``ObservableCollection which I'm binding to a `Pivot` control. This `ObservableCollection` has a child that is also an `ObservableCollection` and I'm trying to bind a `GridView` in each `Pivotitem`'s body.

I've tested my code-behind to ensure the collections are populated i.e.

```
// Level 1 ObservableCollection
foreach (var dchallenge in ChallengesList)
{
    // Level 2 ObservableCollection
    Debug.WriteLine(dchallenge.Name);
    foreach (var dactivity in dchallenge.Activities)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(dactivity.Name);
    }
}
```

And its output is as expected.

For reference, my model is as follows:

```
public class Challenge
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }

    public class Activity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public long Hash { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally, my view:

```
<Pivot x:Name="Items" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ChallengesList, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="20,417,0,0">
    <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Challenge">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="16"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Challenge">

            <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}" MaxWidth="300" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Activities" FontWeight="Medium" MaxWidth="300" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>

                <!--<GridView DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Activities}" SelectionMode="None"
                          IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False" CanDragItems="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
                    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Challenge">
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                </GridView>-->

            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

A `GridView` may not be the control that I finally settle on, but if I know how to bind it then I should be able to use that knowledge with another control.

Intellisense helps a lot in determining which properties are available, but `Activities` isn't one. I only get strings such as `Name` and `Description` which work correctly (first two `TextBlock`).

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you are using the wrong `DataType` in the inner `GridView`. The type in `Activities` collection is `Challenge.Activity`, which is a nested class and nested classes are denoted by plus sign (`+`) in XAML, so `data:Challenge+Activity`:

```
<GridView DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Activities}" SelectionMode="None"
    IsItemClickEnabled="False" IsSwipeEnabled="False" CanDragItems="False"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Challenge+Activity">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

VS may still throw some warnings but those will disappear after successful compilation.

Comment: This compiles and runs sometimes. When it doesn't, I get a `XDG0008 The name "Challenge+Activity" does not exist in the namespace "using:Braytech_3.Models".`

Comment: That is quite unusual. The easiest solution theb would be just to take the `Activity` class out of the `Challebge` class to be able to refer to it just as `data:Activity`